# If $x \leq y \leq z$, and both sides of the equation are defined, then $\frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z }{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z} = \tan y.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Show that if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence, with $x \leq y \leq z$, and both sides of the equation are defined, then 
$$\frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z }{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z} = \tan y.$$

---

I have no idea how to even start this problem, I'm stuck.  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can take the terms of the arithmetic progression as $x=a-h,y=a,z=a+h$ then you have 
$$\sin(a-h)=\sin a\cos h-\cos a\sin h\\\sin(a+h)=\sin a\cos h+\cos a\sin h\\\cos(a-h)=\cos a\cos h+\sin a\sin h\\\cos(a+h)=\cos a\cos h-\sin a\sin h$$ It follows 
$$\frac{\sin(a-h)+\sin a+\sin(a+h)}{\cos(a-h)+\cos a+\cos(a+h)}=\frac{\sin a(2\cos h+1)}{\cos a (2\cos h+1)}=\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}= \tan a$$

Edited.

Comment: @Steven Gregory: I fail to see what has been your edit. Anyway it must have been something good and I appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You hsd (and still have) $\cosh$ instead of $\cos h$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=y-d$ and $z=y+d$ with $d>0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z }{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z}& = \frac{\sin (y-d) + \sin y + \sin (y+d) }{\cos (y-d) + \cos y + \cos (y+d)}\\
& = \frac{2\sin y \cos d + \sin y}{2 \cos y \cos d + \cos y}\\
& = \tan y.
\end{align*}